# Creating domains for every "logical" domain

Tags: sql

I have a databases class in which the prof wants us to create domains for every type, even when these just end up being aliases to other types. For example, instead of using the default `DATE` type, we would create out own type depending on what kind of day it is (eg, `OrderDate`).

I'm wondering if this is common or a best practice.

I can think of some pros and cons to this approach. A pro is that it makes it clear exactly what the domain is intended for, and typically we'd only compare fields if they have the same domain and any other comparison is something to watch for (since it could be comparing apples to oranges). But as a con, this also makes it more confusing to work with the types, as we'd have to refer to the domain declaration to figure out what kind of type a column really is (not that we need to do this too often).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a particularly common practice.  For instance, I have worked on many databases over the years and I have never used such substitutions for base types.

In your example, for instance, an order date may be an order date.  But, I might want to know the how long ago that was in the past -- this requires "mixing" types because the current date (`sysdate`? `now()`? `getdate()`?  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?) is not an `OrderDate`.  Or I might want to know how long after the order the first complaint or first return was made.  Even if the conversion is invisible and automatic, why introduce incompatible types?

Another issue is that different databases differ in their support for user-defined data types.  So, code using user defined types would likely make code more difficult to port to a different database.  Why limit future options?

There are some occasional uses for user defined types *do* have a place for particular new types that might be needed -- complex numbers and points perhaps.  There may even be some situations in some databases where a user defined type on a base type is useful -- for instance, to get represent a telephone number consistently.  Using them liberally as substitutes for built-in types? It seems like overkill, complicating the code, hampering some important queries, and limiting future portability options.